# Scroll-to-fixed navigation doesn't stick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

[using this guide](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/forum-tip-create-a-sticky-navigation-with-css-and-jquery-2), I've been trying to make this navigation work but still no luck. 
I tried fiddling and editing with the javascript/css and this is my code so far:

https://codepen.io/seakongrawd/pen/MmerGO

```
MmerGO
```

I have a feeling that the problem is caused by the positioning of the divs in the CSS. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your class from:

```
.navigation-scroll { position: fixed, width: 100%, top: 0px; }
```

to:

```
#navigation.navigation-scroll  { position: fixed, width: 100%, top: 0px; }
```

and everything will work!

The reason it is not working currently is because #navigation is a more specific selector than .navigation-scroll. By making a chained selector of #navigation.navigation-scroll, you are declaring a more specific selector which is what will be displayed.

Comment: I especially like the elaborate explanation of how and why.

Comment: Thanks for the quicky reply! It works! Changed to > header, #navigation.navigation-scroll {position:fixed; width:100%; top:0;}

Comment: You don't need to include the header, part in this. You're very welcome, happy to help.

Comment: :) The header is used in another part.